# How to send a ios Push Notification (Azure Notif Hub) with media attachment?

Tags: ios, azure, apple-push-notifications, azure-blob-storage, azure-notificationhub

We have a Web App to compose notification which a user sends a push notification message (Azure Notification Hub) and also can upload PDF/Word as attachment. How should i handle it on the phone side when it receives the notification? Should i save the PDF/Word to Azure Blob Storage when they upload from the Webapp and point to that URL when it receives on the phone end? What is the best way to architect this?

Answer (score 0):

You can send optional custom data as part of the push payload. The data will be sent in the key-value format. This custom data can be intercepted in the app through Push SDK callback.

There are few reserved keywords that can be set via custom data.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/ios#custom-data-in-your-notifications

mutable-content: Add this key with a value of 1 to enable media attachments. The application needs to support a service extension to download and handle the attachment content. For more information you can refer to Apple documentations.

Comment: Hi DashleenBhandari thanks for your response... How do i send a Push Notification message from a WEB App POST to a Mobile Phone is this using NotificationHub? Should i expose a REST API that gets the data when the push message is passed from the mobile end?